# Are files specified in .gitignore pushed (uploaded) to remote repo by default?

Tags: git, github

In my local repo, I have large files that I don't wish to commit or upload to the remote repo. If I add these files to .gitignore, will they still be uploaded to the remote repo by `git push` command?

Comment: If they're already being tracked by the repository, yes. gitignore only prevents `git add` from adding them, but if they're already added and thus tracked, then yes, git will keep track of them.

Comment: `git push` does not push single files, it pushes commits that link to snapshots of files that were added to that commit. Simply having files on disk is not a problem, but adding them and then committing them, then after this they will be tracked for changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git push` command sends *commits*, not files.  Each commit then contains *every* file (that it contains; see below).  So to answer the question you asked—whether `git push` uploads any of the files listed in the `.gitignore`—you must inspect the *commits* to see if they *contain* those files.

The name `.gitignore` is inherently wrong: it does not make Git *ignore* files.  The thing is, a *correct* name would be so unwieldy as to be unusable: it would be something like `.git-do-not-auto-add-these-files-if-they-are-untracked-and-if-they-are-untracked-do-not-complain-about-them-being-untracked-when-I-run-git-status`.  It has one more effect, which is rare but important too: it gives Git permission to *clobber* those files in particular circumstances.  So a fully-correct name would be even worse.  But those two things, which are all about *untracked* files, are the two common ones.

So: what is all this stuff about *untracked files* in the first place?  What makes a file "untracked"?  To answer this question, we have to start with the reason Git exists at all, which is the commit.

#### Git is all about commits

Those new to Git often think it's about files.  It isn't: it's about commits.  Commits do *contain* files, but Git usually deals in whole commits at a time.  Or, if they don't think Git is about *files*, beginners often think that Git is about *branches*, and again, it is not: it's still really about commits.  Branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—do matter, because they help us (and Git) *find* the commits.  But it's the commits that *really* matter.  **If you're going to use Git at all, you must learn what a commit is and does for you.**

Each commit:

- Is numbered.  The "number" of a commit is big, ugly, and random-looking.  It's actually a universally-unique ID expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), such as [<sup><sub>`dcc0cd074f0c639a0df20461a301af6d45bd582e`</sub></sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcc0cd074f0c639a0df20461a301af6d45bd582e).  That number, once assigned to *that* commit, means *that* commit, and never any other commit.  This is how two different Git repositories decide whether they have the same commit: they either have the number, in which case they have *that* commit, or one does and one doesn't, and then the one that doesn't have it needs to get the commit from the one that does.
- Is completely read-only.  All Git internal objects are this way—it's necessary to make the numbering scheme work.
- Stores a full archive of every file that Git "knew about" at the time you, or whoever, made the commit.  The files *in* the commit are stored indirectly, in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* form, so that two different files with the same content, or two commits that have the same file with the same content, store the file only *once*.  So, while every commit has a full archive of every file, all the commits also *share* all the files, so that the repository doesn't get enormously bloated.
- Also stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  It includes some date-and-time-stamps.  It includes any commit log message you'd like to put in.  And, crucially for Git's own internal operation, each commit stores a *list of previous commit hash IDs*.  This list is usually just one entry long: that means *this* commit comes right after its listed *parent* commit.

It's this list-of-parents, which strings commits together *backwards*, that forms the real branch information inside a repository.  For instance, suppose we have a string of commits that *ends* at one with a hash we'll call `H` (for `H`ash).  Commit `H` stores the hash ID of some earlier commit.  We say that `H` *points to* this earlier commit:

```
            <-H
```

If we call the earlier commit `G`, and draw it in, we have:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Of course `G` also points to a still-earlier commit, which points backwards yet again, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

and that is a "branch".  To *find* this branch, Git needs to know the actual hash ID of commit `H`, and we stick that in a *branch name* and say that the name *points to* `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

If we have multiple branch names, each name just points to one commit:

```
          I--J   <-- feature-1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- feature-2
```

Now there are three "last" commits: `H` is the *last* commit on `main` as before, but `J` is the last commit on `feature-1`, and `L` is the last commit on `feature-2`.  Note that commits up through `H` are on *all three* branches (this is peculiar to Git; most version control systems don't work this way).

#### If files in commits are read-only and Git-only, how can we work with them?

The fact is that each commit *is* read-only, and the files inside the commit can only be read *by* Git itself.  So before we can *use* a commit, we have to have Git *extract* the commit.  We do this with `git checkout` or `git switch`: we pick some commit, by hash ID like `H` or by name like `main` which provides Git with hash ID `H`, and say *extract that commit:*

```
git switch main
```

Git will read *all* the files from commit `H` and expand them into ordinary everyday files.  Git puts these files in a work area, which Git calls our *working tree* or *work-tree*.

That, then, answers the question about how we get work done: we use the working tree copies of the files.  *These files are not in Git!*  They came *out* of Git—at least, the initial ones did—but they are not *in* Git at this point.

#### Git's *index* or *staging area*

After we work on some file in the working tree, we might want Git to use that file—plus all the other files that we *didn't* change—to make a new commit.  In other version control systems, we would generally run their "make commit" verb:

```
hg commit
```

for instance.  They would figure out which files we changed and make the new commit.  Git, alas, does not make it this easy.  Instead, Git demands that we run:

```
git add updated-file
git commit
```

The first command—the `git add` step—tells Git: *Read the working tree file, compress it into your internal Gitty format with de-duplication, and insert that into your index / staging-area, ready to be committed.*

The secret here—it's not really a secret, but it's not always advertised or taught correctly—is that Git *already has every existing checked-out file in its index / staging-area*.  This thing—the thing Git calls either the index or the staging area, depending on which bit of Git documentation is doing this calling—holds in it your *proposed next commit*.

When you first switch to some particular commit, Git removes from your working tree all the checked-out files that *came out* of whatever commit you *were* using, as recorded in its index.  It also removes all the checked-out files from its index.  Then it installs, into its index and into your working tree, all the files that go with the new commit you want to use.  That is, if we did:

```
git switch main
```

we had all the files from `H`, but if we then decided to look at `feature-1` instead and ran:

```
git switch feature-1
```

Git *removed* all the files from `H` and *replaced* them with the files from `J`, which is the commit to which the name `feature-1` points.

**There are a couple of important things to know about this remove-and-replace step:**

- First, Git *only* removes-and-replaces any files it *has* to.  Git is already de-duplicating files, so it *knows* which files in `H` are the same in `J`.  For any file that's the same in both commits, it can skip the R(emove)-and-R(eplace) job.  For files that are in `H` but *not* in `J`, it has to do the first R—the remove—without a replace, and for files that are in `J` but not `H`, it has to just replace.
- Second, Git *only* does an R-and-R for the files it *knows about*.  But what are those files?  That's where the index comes in.

Because your working tree is a regular directory (or folder, if you prefer that term) with regular everyday files in it, you can *create files that Git doesn't know about*.  These are your *untracked files*.  That gives us the definition of an "untracked" file: an untracked file is one that is not in Git's index *right now*.  This is extremely important, so let's repeat it.

#### An untracked file is a file that is not in Git's index *right now*

This is the key to making new commits, and also the key to `.gitignore`.  Files that *are* in Git's index *right now* are *tracked*.  Files that *are not* in Git's index *right now* are *untracked*.  The "right now" part is important, because:

- `git switch` and `git checkout` fill in the index; but
- `git add` reads a working tree file and copies it into the index; and
- `git rm` removes a file from both the working tree and the index.

This gives you several ways to *change* what's in the index / staging-area.  (There are more ways, such as `git restore`, but we'll just cover these three for now.)  Using `git rm --cached`, you can remove a file from Git's index without removing it from the working tree, too, so it's easy to take a file from tracked to untracked with `git rm --cached`, or from untracked to tracked with `git add`.

#### Git builds new commits from whatever is in the index *right now*

When you run:

```
git commit
```

Git makes a snapshot of all the files that are in the index *right then*, as of the form they have *in* the index *at that time*.  So if you:

```
git switch main
<modify one file - say, README.txt>
git add file
<modify the file again>
```

you currently have *three versions* of `README.txt`: there's one unchangeable one in the *current commit*, a second one in Git's index, and a third one in your working tree.  If you run `git commit`, it's that second one—the one in Git's index—that goes in the new commit.

(Note that `git commit -a` is roughly equivalent to `git add -u && git commit`.  That is, the `-a` option merely does an *update*-add of all the files that are *already in Git's index*.  So truly-new files require a separate `git add` step.)

#### This is where `.gitignore` comes in

You can explicitly run:

```
git add some-file
```

or, if you like, you can run an en-masse "add everything here" with:

```
git add .
```

Both operations tell Git to add a file; the second one tells Git to add *all* the files from the current directory.  But some files *should not* be put in new commits, and it would be painful to force you to `git add` individual files instead of letting you use `git add .` to just make Git figure things out.

Besides this, the `git status` command will run two diffs:

- The first diff compares the `HEAD` (current) commit to Git's index.  For each file that is *the same*, Git says nothing at all.  For each file that is *different*—including newly added or removed—Git tells you about it, saying `staged for commit`.  That's because whatever is in the index *will be* in the next commit, and if it's *different*, that's interesting.  If you have a big project, with thousands of files, you probably don't care that `dull/1` through `dull/999` are all unchanged; what you care about is that `important.code` *is* changed.  This `git status` diff will tell you that.
- The second diff compares the index to your working tree.  For each file that is *the same*, Git says nothing.  For files that are *different*, Git tells you about them, saying `not staged for commit`.  But *new* files—files that aren't in Git's index, but *are* in your working tree—are separated out.  Git tells you about them not as "new" but rather as `untracked`.

To prevent `git status` from being uselessly noisy about 10,000 untracked files that *should* be untracked, and to make `git add .` useful by not adding the 10,000 files, Git will read the poorly-named file `.gitignore`.  These are the files that Git will (a) *shut up* about, and (b) *not* add even though you said `git add .`.

**This has no effect on files that are already in Git's index.**  If the file *is* in Git's index, it *is tracked* and it *will be in the next commit*.  Listing a file in `.gitignore` doesn't make it untracked and does not make Git ignore it: it just means that *if* it *is* untracked, Git won't *complain about it* and won't *auto-add it*.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, if you explicitly *try* to add it with `git add listed-ignored-file`, Git will tell you that it's both currently untracked *and* listed in `.gitignore`, but—if you haven't disabled the hint—that you can override this with `git add -f`.  Some people like to use this trick to ignore "everything" (with `*` in a `.gitignore`, for instance), and then force-add the few files that they *don't* want to ignore.  I personally don't like to do this, but it does work.  Just note that if you *do* use this trick, `git rm --cached -r . && git add .` will do bad things.

---

#### Diagnosing whether a file is "ignored"

Suppose you have some repository in which someone, at some point, said to ignore `*.zorg` files.  Maybe that was the right thing to do at that time, even.  But now you *do* need to commit some or all of the files in which you store your bad guys, so you *don't* want `*.zorg` ignored.

You run `ls` and you see:

```
jean-baptiste.emanuel.zorg
```

You run `git status` and it *doesn't list* `jean-baptiste.emanuel.zorg`.

Is the file unchanged, or is it changed-but-ignored, and not present in Git's index *right now?*

You can run:

```
git add jean-baptiste.emanuel.zorg
```

If it says nothing, the file *was* added; `git status` will now tell you whether it's changed.  If it says that the file is explicitly ignored but you can use `-f` to override, you can `git add -f jean-baptiste.emanuel.zorg` to get it added.

You can also run:

```
git ls-files jean-baptiste.emanuel.zorg
```

If this says *nothing*, the file is ignored.  Or you can run:

```
git check-ignore jean-baptiste.emanuel.zorg
```

(consider adding `-v` as well).  If this says *nothing*, the file is *not* ignored, perhaps because it's been force-added.

Comment: Wow this is a very long answer! Thank you for all these details

Answer (score 0):

If you add the correct path to the file in the `.gitignore`, the file won't be added if you use `git add .` and it won't be pushed if you type `git push`.

So short answer, no

Comment: This answer should clarify that it applies only to files that are not already being tracked. You use `git add .` also to stage changes, so the OP might still execute `git add .` and commit and push, with those large files being part of the commit, provided they have been added previously.