# Keep Downstream Branch Updated - Keeps pulling unwanted files

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm new to git and I'm going in circles. I'm not sure this is a normal use case, but I have lets say a branch called `dev` and then I have two downstream branches `html` and `xml`. Each has "whitelist" `.gitignore`. They are for cloning into server directories and I want only the files needed in the branch. (WebServer and Network Share for sideloading Office App)

I'm trying to make it so when I push to dev, the "downstream" branches `html` and `xml` pull/get pushed only the updates files whitelisted in there respective `.gitignore` files.

First off here is my setup so as not to avoid the X-Y question problem as I may be doing this incorrectly..

I have githooks setup that when I push to dev, it runs a script that goes into the gitrepo dir and then runs the following:

```
git checkout html
git pull #probably not needed as it should be updated, but no harm
git pull --no-edit origin dev
git add .
git commit -m "pulled from dev"
git push
```

Same for the xml.

Here is the HTML whitelist/.gitignore:

```
/*
!/Commands/
!/Content/
!/Images/
!/Functions/
!/Scripts/
!*.css
!*.html
!*.js
!.gitignore

!/ExcelWebAddIn1
/ExcelWebAddIn1/*

!/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/
/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*

!ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Commands/
!ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Content/
!ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Images/
!ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Functions/
!ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Scripts/
!ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*.js
!ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*.html
!ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*.css
```

Here is the message I keep getting and the "extra files" pulled which were modified as part of my test, but shouldn't be in this branch at all. I initialized the branch without them and have used `git rm --cached ExcelWebAddIn1/..` repeatedly and removed and re-cloned my working git directory many times.

```
...\git\vsdev>git pull --no-edit origin dev
remote: Enumerating objects: 17, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), 724 bytes | 3.00 KiB/s, done.
From ssh://git.freesoftwareservers.com:10022/freesoftwareservers/vsdev
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
   47109fd..5fb82df  dev        -> origin/dev
CONFLICT (modify/delete): ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Manifest/vsdev.localhost.xml deleted in HEAD and modified in 5fb82df36c84c4cc84536a60ecb243088a58d47b.  Version 5fb82df36c84c4cc84536a60ecb243088a58d47b of ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Manifest/vsdev.localhost.xml left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Manifest/vsdev.prod.xml deleted in HEAD and modified in 5fb82df36c84c4cc84536a60ecb243088a58d47b.  Version 5fb82df36c84c4cc84536a60ecb243088a58d47b of ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Manifest/vsdev.prod.xml left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

So in essence, what am I doing incorrectly? Is it a misconfiguration of `.gitignore` as I have been adjusting that thinking it was the issue. Or perhaps the pull command can be tailored?

As well, is there a way to run the pull/push commands without working on a local copy? IE: I'd like my githook script to just push `dev` to `html` and then cd to the webserver and run `pull`. Without having the need for another "clone" directory just sitting for the script to utilize.

Comment: `.gitignore` does not cause files to be ignored. See, e.g., [Are files specified in .gitignore pushed (uploaded) to remote repo by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70607859/1256452) You're getting these merge conflicts because some commits have the files, and some don't, and the merge operation is finding that the *merge base* **does** have the file, one of the two tip commits *does* have the file, and the other tip commit *doesn't* have the file: that's the very definition of a modify/delete merge conflict.

Comment: Note that while you don't need a local checkout to run `git push`, you *do* need a repository containing commits to run `git push`. Since `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*, you need exactly those things that are needed for `git fetch` plus the chosen second command: a local repository and—because the second command is normally either `git merge` or `git rebase`—a working tree.

Comment: Yes but that is what I want, the `dev` branch should have all files the `html` branch is whitelisted only some of the files. I'm thinking that my "whitelist" should be just a bunch of specific checkouts paired with a commit/push up to html? IE: `git checkout origin/dev -- ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*.html`

Comment: Possibly (I haven't read your question closely enough). Note that `git checkout <commit-specifier> -- <paths>` means *extract the given files from the given commit, writing them to both the index/staging-area and to the working tree*. You may then need to make a new commit from the result. At this point, regardless of what's in the merge base, `origin/dev` and your current commit will contain the same versions of those files, so if you're merging `origin/dev` *with* your current commit, Git will decree that the correct merge result is to have that (shared) version of that file.

Comment: To be clear the `html` and `xml` branches will never have any changes made to them, they are strictly for organizing files and basically being able to cd into my webroot and clone that branch and not have a bunch of unnecessary/sensitive files. @torek

Comment: In that case, `html` and `xml` shouldn't be branches at all: they consist entirely of computer-generated outputs. The repository should contain only the inputs, not the outputs. Generate the outputs and use something (other than Git) to deploy them (Git makes a terrible deployment system in general, though since I don't do deployment, I don't have any particular system I recommend, though I hear rsync works pretty well).

Comment: .... Ok, when I said X-Y problem, I didn't mean convince me not to use git I just meant maybe I'm using git wrong to get the results I want. Ive already determined I can do what I want via multiple checkouts of the specific files. Git makes a great deployment system... I just need to iron out the kinks/learn the tool.

Comment: Well, my free advice (that Git is a terrible deployment system) is worth at least as much as you paid for it! 

Comment: Fair enuf, this is a Home server project that I will be the only contributor, eventually it'll be destined for much greater things and proper tools!! I learned a lot tonight, got into merge and rebase and checking gitignore and tracked files, at the end of the day I'm happy to just make my whitelists basically be a bunch of git checkouts! Unless you have a better way of accomplishing my goals via git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based on my suspicions and @toreks comments this is not a normal GIT usage. Add that to the fact I was new a git and it took me a while to figure out. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what threw me off was the idea that a file wasn't tracked if it wasn't commit in that branch, but I believe when I pull a file from master, even if its not committed in that branch its still considered "tracked".

Anyway, these two lines helped me figure things out a lot:

View files ignored:

```
nano -c .gitignore ;  find . -not -path './.git/*' | git check-ignore -v --stdin
```

View Files Tracked:

```
git ls-files **/*
```

And finally I realized the method I should use for this scenario is strictly `checkout`. I made `.gitignore` files for the `html/xml` repos, as I had already figured them out, but at this point, they should only ever be checking out the correct files, that is my "whitelist".

Here is how I restarted and setup the two repos:

```
git checkout dev
git push origin --delete localhostxml
git branch -d localhostxml
git checkout -b localhostxml
rm * -R
```

---

```
cat <<'EOF'>.gitignore
/*
!.gitignore
!update_branch.sh
!/ExcelWebAddIn1
/ExcelWebAddIn1/*
!/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1
/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1/*
!ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Manifest
/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Manifest/*
!ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Manifes/*localhost.xml
EOF
```

---

```
cat <<'EOF'>update_branch.sh
!#/bin/bash

git checkout origin/dev -- ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Manifest/*.localhost.xml
git add . 
git commit -m "pulled from dev" 
git push --set-upstream origin localhostxml 
git push origin localhost
EOF
chmod +x update_branch.sh
./update_branch.sh
```

---

```
git checkout dev
git push origin --delete html
git branch -d html
git checkout -b html
rm * -R
```

---

```
cat <<'EOF'>.gitignore
/*
!.gitignore
!update_branch.sh
!/ExcelWebAddIn1
/ExcelWebAddIn1/*
!/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web
/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*
!/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*.html
!/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*.js
!/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*.css
!/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Content/
!/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Images/
!/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Functions/
!/ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Scripts/

EOF
```

---

```
cat <<'EOF'>update_branch.sh
!#/bin/bash

git checkout origin/dev -- ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*.html
git checkout origin/dev -- ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*.css
git checkout origin/dev -- ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/*.js
git checkout origin/dev -- ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Content/
git checkout origin/dev -- ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Images/
git checkout origin/dev -- ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Functions/
git checkout origin/dev -- ExcelWebAddIn1/ExcelWebAddIn1Web/Scripts/

git add . 
git commit -m "pulled from dev" 
git push --set-upstream origin html
git push origin html
EOF
chmod +x update_branch.sh
./update_branch.sh
```

Finally my hook script:

```
#!/bin/bash

home=/opt/git/local/vsdev/
cd $home
git pull

git checkout html
./update_branch.sh

git checkout localhostxml
./update_branch.sh

git checkout prodxml
./update_branch.sh

html=/opt/odev/html/vsdev/
cd $html
git checkout html
git pull origin html

xml=/mnt/zfs/raid-z/odev/vsdev/
cd $xml
git pull

cd $home

touch /tmp/hookin
```

Comment: @torek I realize your of the , this is the wrong tool, thought, but does the above look like how you would do it if you had to?